# React Native handling ellipsis when multiple Text components in a row

Tags: layout, react-native, flexbox, ellipsis

I am trying to build a comments section in React Native but I'm having trouble handling text overflow and ellipsis properly.

The structure is simple and looks as follows:
[image]

Ideally, when the username is long enough it should be trimmed and the action name should be pushed all the way to the right until it reaches the timestamp like this:

[image]

The closest I got was using this code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    commentRow: {
        padding: 10
    },
    commentTopRow: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    commentTitle: {
        flex: 1
    },
    author: {
        fontWeight: '500'
    },
    commentBody: {
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 5
    }
});

<View style={styles.commentRow}>
    <View style={styles.commentTopRow}>
        <Text style={styles.commentTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
            <Text style={styles.author}>User Name</Text>
            <Text style={styles.action}> commented</Text>
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.timestamp}>8h</Text>
    </View>
    <Text style={styles.commentBody}>comment body</Text>
</View>
```

which yields the following results:

[image]
[image]

Any help in figuring out a unique structure and style set that will handle both cases would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, I've also had an intermediary version where the long username would work but then the short one was broken, keeping "commented" pinned all the way to the right at all times. This had no `commentTitle` wrapper, `flex: 1` and `numberOfLines={1}` were set on `author`.

Answer (score 6):

According to Facebook's [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html),

> In React Native flex does not work the same way that it does in CSS. flex is a number rather than a string, and it works according to the css-layout library at https://github.com/facebook/css-layout.
>
> When flex is -1, the component is normally sized according width and height. However, if there's not enough space, the component will shrink to its minWidth and minHeight.

So basically you need to set the correct `flex` values for your components. I suppose you do not want `commented` and `8h` to shrink. Then, you need to set `flex` values to `0` for these components to make them inflexible to shrink. And set `0` to `long long user name` to make it flexible to shrink when space is not enough.

Comment: Can you please correct the `long user name` value to `-1` instead of `0`?

Answer (score -1):

This gonna be work

```
 <View style={styles.commentRow}>
     <View style={styles.commentTopRow}>
         <View style={styles.commentTitle}>
             <Text numberOfLines={1}>
                 <Text style={styles.author}>User Name</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.action}> commented</Text>
             </Text>
         </View>
         <View>
            <Text style={styles.timestamp}>8h</Text>
         </View>
     </View>
     <Text style={styles.commentBody}>comment body</Text>
 </View>
```

In a word, you should use The `View` to layout, not the `Text`